# Getting JSONP via jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsonp

**UPDATE 1:**

This is what I get in the browser if I type

http://www.remote_host.com/feed.php?callback=jsonpCallBack

```
{
    "rss": {
        "channels": [
            {
                "title": "title goes here",
                "link": "http://www.remote_server.com/feed.php",
                "description": "description goes here",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "title": "item title goes here",
                        "link": "item link goes here",
                        "pubDate": "item date goes here",
                        "description": "item description goes here"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "item title goes here",
                        "link": "item link goes here",
                        "pubDate": "item date goes here",
                        "description": "item description goes here"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "item title goes here",
                        "link": "item link goes here",
                        "pubDate": "item date goes here",
                        "description": "item description goes here"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So this is not jsonp?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have the following script where I am trying to get json data from a remote host:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_json_feed();

    function get_json_feed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.remote_host.com/feed.php?type=json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function(json) {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But for some reason I am getting an error and warning:

> Warning: Resource interpreted as
>   Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html.
>
> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token :

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u try to change the type??

Comment: @diEcho, which type?  I have 2 types at clientside type and dataType, and I have a type at serverside.

Comment: This sounds like the server does not return JSONP. You should try (a) `feed.php?type=jsonp` and (b) if the server supports JSONP, it normally accepts a parameter with which you specify the callback name, something like: `feed.php?type=jsonp&callback=?`. You have to read the documentation of the service you are using.

Comment: write  `jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',` in ur option

Comment: @diEcho: Oh thanks, forgot about that... still has to be specified if the name is different...

Comment: @Felix Kling, how can I check if what you're saying the reason by I am getting the error?  I am trying to create the service myself.  The remote server belongs to me.

Comment: @diEcho, I've just tried that, and I seem to be getting the same errors.

Comment: Try some combinations of parameters in the browser and/or read the documentation. E.g. if you type `http://www.remote_host.com/feed.php?type=json` in the address bar  and the response does not look like `funcName({...})` but like `{...}`, then you get JSON and not JSONP.

Comment: If the server belongs to you, you also have to set it up to return JSONP.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I thought I had.  When I manually type in the url for the server, I get back json data on the screen.

Comment: JSON is not JSONP. Read about JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP and see @Pointy's answer.

Comment: Please see update 1 to confirm.

Comment: No, that is not JSONP, it is just JSON. Again, read the Wikipedia link and see @Pointy's answer. In this case , the response should look like `jsonpCallBack({...})`, where `{...}` is the JSON you posted above.

Comment: Thanks.  Will do that and will be back in a few moments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSONP "protocol" relies on the site replying to your request with a JavaScript statement of the form,

```
 someFunction( someJSON )
```

The name of the function is supplied as an argument from your code, with the idea being that the response script, once consumed and interpreted by the browser, will result in a call to that function with a parsed blob of JSON — which is to say, a JavaScript object. The jQuery library will do some of the bookeeping work for you, even to the extent of creating the globally-scoped function to call (which will be code that just calls the callback you supply as the "success" argument).

Thus, you should check what the actual response from that server looks like.  It sounds to me as if it may not be a server prepared to respond that way. You *might* need to make sure there's an extra parameter on your URL, of the form "callback=?".

Comment: Right - that's just plain JSON. The JSONP protocol requires that the JSON be wrapped in a function call.  The browser fetches the content from the server by creating a `<script>` tag.  When the script is fetched (the function call around that JSON), the function call will take place.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly what error you are facing, but there are some useful tips for using `jsonp` **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

- `error`: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.
- write `jsonp: 'callback', jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback'` in ajax parameters.
  Setting `jsonp` to callback and then setting `jsonpCallback` to jsonpCallback makes the querystring look like this:

  http://domain.com/jsonp-demo.php?callback=jsonpCallback&name=watever
- Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Will add an extra `?callback=?` to the end of your URL to specify the callback.

Your complete script would look like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#useJSONP").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://domain.com/jsonp-demo.php',
                data: {name: 'Chad'},
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
                success: function(){
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
        });

    });

    function jsonpCallback(data){
        $('#jsonpResult').text(data.message);
    }
    </script>
```

**[Example here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682)**

Answer (score 3):

Looks like server returns wrong Content-type header.

Comment: I have added a content type header `header("content-type: text/javascript");`, so the warning has now gone.