# getJSON error: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

I need to get a json file from here:

https://raw.github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/master/category_lists/en/category.json

However, I keep receiving the error:

**Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain**

I am trying to get the file by doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://raw.github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/master/category_lists/en/category.json',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("here");
    },
    error: function () { alert("Error reading category.json");}
});
```

Is there a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213853/getting-jsonp-via-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Its because the `Response Headers` show that the content received is

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

And that you're code expects a `JSON` response from the url. That's the reason you are getting that error.

**Solution:**

One thing you can do is that you can load the response as `text/plain` and later convert it to a `json` object by

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(yourString);
```

**Updated Code:**

Well, you can avoid the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, by loading the remote response from your own domain, this will act as a proxy server and it will load the remote resource for you

```
$.ajax({
    url : url, // url on your domain, that will load the remote response for you
    dataType : 'html', // load the response as plain/html
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data); // convert the received response to a JSON object
    }
});​
```

Comment: I changed the dateType to html, however I get the Origin .... not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, which JSONP is supposed to solve?

Comment: But you cant load the response as JSONP since the response headers contain Content-type: text/html